# Can I transform two log variables into one using multiplication in VECM time series model?

Tags: time-series, normality-assumption, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model

I performed a Vector error correction model using Tourist Arrivals as a dependent Variable and Real GDP, Public Road Transport operated distance and Public Railway Transport operated distance as Independent variables. Although the model was significant it did not pass the Normality test. (Image1- model1)

[image: Image1- model1]

Then I converted two Transport variables into one using multiplication and performed the model again and this time whole model passed the normality test. (Image2- Model2)

[image: Image2- Model2]

I just want to know if can I use this Variable transformation in my model and if so could you please advise any reference for it.
Highly appreciate your comment on this.

Thank You.

Comment: Do you care about the interpretation of the model? If so, does having log(rail)*log(road) in your model make any sense?

Comment: Hi Richard Hardy, I am going to measure the improvement of the transport sector through the product of road and railway variables. Because, if the product has increasing trending it means overall transport sector has a positive impact.

Comment: Please add new information not only in comments, but as an edit to the post. Few people actuallt see & read comments!